# Prevent rmdir -p from traversing above a certain directory

Tags: linux, bash, file-management, find

I hacked together this script to `rsync` some files over `ssh`. The `--remove-source-files` option of `rsync` seems to remove the files it transfers, which is what I want. However, I also want the directories those files are placed in to be gone as well.

The current part of the `find` command, `-exec rmdir -p {} ;` tries to remove the parent directory (in this case, `/srv/torrents`), but fails because it doesn't have the right permissions. What I'd like to do is stop `rmdir` from traversing above the directory `find` is run in, or find another solution to get rid of all the empty folders. I've thought of using some kind of loop with `find` and running `rmdir` without the `-p` switch, but I thought it wouldn't work out.

Essentially, **is there an alternative way to remove all the empty directories under the parent directory?**

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='<hostname>'
USER='<username>'
DIR='<destination directory>'
SOURCE='/srv/torrents/'

rsync -e "ssh -l $USER" --remove-source-files -h -4 -r --stats -m --progress -i $SOURCE $HOST:$DIR
find $SOURCE -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -prune -exec rmdir -p \{\} \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that `rmdir` won't remove a non-empty directory:

```
rmdir {,.}?*/ 2>/dev/null
```

or, if your version of `rmdir` has the option:

```
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty {,.}?*/
```

The weird looking glob expands to include regular directories and hidden directories, but exclude `.` and `..`.

You don't have to use `find` unless you need to get at directories below the current level.

**Edit:**

Try:

```
find -type d -empty -delete
```

That does a depth-first search and deletes all empty nested directories.

Comment: @Dennis: But this won't remove empty directories under the current level (e.g. if `./foo/bar/baz/` are all empty folders, it won't remove them.) I need something that will get at directories below the current level, hence why I'm using find.

Comment: @thepurplepixel: See my edit.

Comment: Just like to point out for any future people reading this question that the edited command requires the `-mindepth 1` parameter as well so it doesn't delete the parent directory.

Comment: @thepurplepixel: That's probably safer, but I just tested it and it didn't delete the parent (current) directory. `mkdir test; cd test; mkdir sub; find -type d -empty -print -delete; cd ..; ls -ld test; ls -lR test`. Still there ("sub" is gone). The directory "test" is not empty until after its contents are deleted (depth-first). Now do `cd test; find -type d -empty -print -delete; cd ..; ls -ld test; ls -lR test` (re-run it when "test" is already empty). *Still there.*

Comment: @Dennis: It may be different for me because I am specifying a certain directory for `find` to run on (`find $DIR -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete`)... who knows? It seems to work for me, and that's what counts! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also do

```
find $SOURCE -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -prune -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: @MrShunz: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work either. It has the same effect as Dennis Williamson's answer. Even if you run it two or three times, it only seems to go two directories deep at most. Thanks, though.